# Flutter : Get doc.id

Tags: flutter

I want to get the doc.id in my List, but the following code is not working, what is the solution please ?

```
QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> userAddressData = await firestore
    .collection('Users')
    .doc(_auth.currentUser?.uid)
    .collection('Address')
    .get();

final docData = userAddressData.docs.map((doc) => {doc.data(), id : doc.id}).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `final docData = userAddressData.docs.map((doc) => {...doc.data(), 'id' : doc.id}).toList();`
Instead of
`final docData = userAddressData.docs.map((doc) => {doc.data(), id : doc.id}).toList();`